# is developing an HTML web app using Notepad++ secure

Tags: html, asp.net, security, web-applications, notepad

I have started on a web app for the ORG i work for, using notepad++ for html and css and of course php and javascript. I must say that the ORG did not used to have software developers, all software they have is off-the-shelf or oracle forms and am a recent grad.

We got a new hire he has much more experience "he claims", the thing is that he has been criticizing me for using notepad++ for html, he instead suggests using ASP.NET in VS. His argument comes from security risks and better support point of view.

The web app will consist of a website for the visitors to browse, in addition to an intranet for employees to use onsite and globally.

So i am not sure if i am on the right track and he is showing off, or i should be following his advice "he could be our new IT manager".

I thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I dont know how a text editor can compromise your webapp security. That is just nonsense. Although he is right that other editors have better support and more functionality, but just from a security point of view, that makes no sense. I would recommend you to move over to Atom (open source) editor, which has a huge community and a lot of packages. Hope this helps!

Comment: ASP.NET is a server side technology of which there are alternatives, such as PHP. HTML is structurual language for representing content for, typically, a brower to show.
Anyway maybe your coworker could be right if you know the asp.net and .net language,or wrong if you are better in php

Comment: Is it possible that you, given your lack of experience, didn't really understand the point they were trying to make, and are actually not asking about what he claimed (or that there is a translation error)?

Comment: @N.Ivanov 
I do understand what you are saying i just wanted to make sure that am not actually being an idiot. I tried to explain that it does not matter what IDE or text editor to use, what matter is the code itself. But i guess he is trying to be bossy or maybe he likes to use the tools he is familiar with. Thank you very much for the help and your suggestions.

Comment: @exSnake Thanks ^^^

Comment: @CodeCaster he made two points the first, he emphasised on the security of HTML itself and then the text editor, and this point does not make any sense even for a novice as myself. His other point was the features and support ASP.NET has online. and no translations error. I just need to understand what he actually after.

Answer (score 3):

The editor you are using has literally nothing to do with the security of the programmed application. Notepad++ is perfectly fine, even though i would recommend something like [Atom](https://atom.io), [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) or [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/).
One thing they have as a "security advantage" over Notepad++ is, that it is easier to install plugins that try to check your code and point out possible bugs. Otherwise blaming the Editor for Security issues is nonsense.

I have no experience with ASP.NET, i tried it a few times but never liked it. I think it comes with some authentication solutions out of the box.

HTML and CSS have very little to do with security. JavaScript and especially PHP is what you have to be careful with. I would recommend to use some kind of PHP framework as there are often well tested authentication components included. Frameworks I know of are [Symfony](https://symfony.com/) and [Laravel](https://laravel.com) (which is built on Symfony).

Comment: I will look into your suggestions, as of the plugins am not using any plugins anyway. Thanks for the clarifications.